# Retrofit com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException error (trailing comma)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm using **retrofit 1.9** for `REST` client. For `Deserialization` gson converter is used.

> The **problem** is that some `JSON` **response** are **invalid**.
>   For example:

```
{
    "foo": 4,
    "bar ": 5,
}
```

The problem is trailing comma.

So I implement custom TypeAdapter, but I still get the same error

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 4 
column 2 path $.bar


public class LikeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<FooBar> {

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, FooBar value) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public FooBar read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return null;
        }

        FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();
        in.beginObject();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.nextName();
            if (name.equals("foo")) {
                int f = in.nextInt();
                fooBar.setFoo(f)
            } else if (name.equals("bar ")) {
                int b = in.nextInt();
                fooBar.setBar(b);
                break;
            }

        }
        return fooBar;
    }


}
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `The problem is that some JSON response are invalid` - JSON specification is strict and this one is simply malformed. Why won't you fix JSON you generate to follow the rules, or (if it's not yours) report problem to whoever manages this server to fix it?

Comment: Assuming you can't change the server... If you're registering a `GsonConverterFactory` there, couldn't you pass a new factory that creates `GsonConverter` overrides which have the chance to clean up the body text before passing on to GSON itself? Not tested, just inferred from the source: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/gson

Comment: Hi.. I am facing a similar yet different problem, where I am not given MalformedJSONException in java code, but getting null as a result of processed json array. Can you suggest something?